# Fabric Crashlytics/Answers not showing up - Installing Fabric as part of android library

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have been requested to this setup: have 2 android projects in 2 different repos. One of the projects is an Android library, and the other is a (or multiple) android applications, importing the library.
This is setup in different repos, so it is not an app with a library module, or vice versa.

The Android library has all of the potential analytics tools we use in the company, and then the app project would just import the android library, and initialize whatever analytics provider it wants to report to.

So far everything "works" but I dont see any data showing up on Fabric's website.

Here are the important pieces of how I have my library setup:

project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // fabric
        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

And then the app level `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

dependencies {
    // fabric
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

And then finally, the app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file contains the apiKey:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx8888xxx"
    />
```

The library initializes Crashlytics/Answers, like this (this is just a test, so its all dirty for now):

```
final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(context)
        .kits(new Crashlytics(), new Answers())
        .debuggable(true)
        .build();
Fabric.with(fabric);
Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier("55555");
Crashlytics.setUserEmail("eduardo@test.com");
Crashlytics.setUserName("EduardoTest");
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Played Song"));
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Played Song")
        .putCustomAttribute("Custom String", "My String")
        .putCustomAttribute("Custom Number", 25));
```

I run the app, and the logs show this:

```
sample_app I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.17.dev
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Installer package name is: null
sample_app D/Beta: Beta by Crashlytics app is not installed
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Exception handling initialization successful
sample_app D/Fabric: Initializing io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric [Version: 1.3.17.dev], with the following kits:
                                                                           com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta [Version: 1.2.5.dev]
                                                                           com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers [Version: 1.3.13.dev]
                                                                           com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics [Version: 2.6.8.dev]
                                                                           com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core [Version: 2.3.17.dev]

sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Opening a new session with ID 123123-1231-12331-123123
sample_app D/Fabric: Requesting settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/com.ancestry.analytics_sample_app/settings
sample_app D/Fabric: Loaded settings:<some settings payload>
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file created.
ample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Finalizing previously open sessions.
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: No open sessions to be closed.
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Closed all previously open sessions
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Starting report processing in 1.0 second(s)...
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file removed: true
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Checking for crash reports...
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: No reports found.
08-16 14:18:09.354 16431-16431/? D/libcrashlytics: Initializing libcrashlytics version 1.1.5
08-16 14:18:09.354 16431-16431/? D/libcrashlytics: Attempting to load unwinder...
08-16 14:18:09.365 16431-16431/? D/libcrashlytics: Done; using libunwind
08-16 14:18:09.365 16431-16431/? D/libcrashlytics: Attempting to register signal handler...
08-16 14:18:09.365 16431-16431/? D/libcrashlytics: Signal handler registered.
08-16 14:18:09.366 16431-16431/? D/libcrashlytics: Initializing native crash handling successful.
08-16 14:18:09.373 16431-16431/? I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.17.dev
```

Any suggestions or feedback as to why this doesn't show up on the Fabric's side?

Thank you!

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Just to confirm, you're not seeing data from the library or the main app?

Comment: Hi Mike. I don't see data on the crashlytics website. I am using, what I think is the unique apikey for a test app we already had on crashlytics (which has a different name and package id) but it never shows users or custom events. I event went through the setup website and all I get is the "listening for events"

Comment: Gotcha, what's interesting to me is this line:
sample_app D/CrashlyticsCore: Installer package name is: null
 (Not sure if you manually removed the package name or not) If you didn't then it makes me think that the init isn't happening within the app until very late.

Comment: I don't know how to change the package installer name, so I'm gonna say I didn't change it :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll prob need the library and app's package name. Feel free to email into support(at)fabric(dot)io if you want to keep it private.

Comment: @MikeBonnell im sorry for the delay. I emailed you the package name.

Comment: Hi. I have the exact same issue. Did you find a fix?